# Why this error shows up in this example? ! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line

Tags: errors, luatex, comments, cprotect

I do not see why this error shows up in this example below.

When putting `\iffalse` to comment a section out, which has `\cprotect` around it, I get an error. When removing `\iffalse`, the error goes away.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\begin{document}

\iffalse
\cprotect\section{my title with some math $\sin x$}
    this is a test
\fi

test
\end{document}
```

Compiling using `lualatex foo3.tex`, it gives the error

```
(./foo3.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 8.
<inserted text>
\fi
l.9 \cprotect
           \section{my title with some math $\sin x$}
?
```

Removing  `\usepackage{cprotect}` the error goes away. Also keeping `\usepackage{cprotect}` but removing `\iffalse`, the error goes away.

Why does this happen? How to keep the section commented out, but still use `cprotect` as I want it for other sections in the file?

TL 2020

```
lualatex --version
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)
```

Comment: You may be abusing/misusing the facilities of the `cprotect` package. Anyway, using `\iffalse ... \fi` seems like a hackish (and definitely not entirely robust..) way to comment out a line or two of code. I suggest you load the `comment` package and place `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` statements (on lines by themselves) around the code chunk in question.

Comment: @Mico thanks! I never heard of the comment package. I will definily check it out now and if it works will let you know and will be happy to accept this an answer. I only wanted to comment this section without the error, that is all.

Comment: @Mico comment package worked! thanks. if you like to post this as answer/workaround will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\iffalse ... \fi` as a method for commenting out a code chunk would appear to be a less than fully robust method.

To truly comment out  code, you could place the `%` (comment) symbol at the start of each line of interest. Alternatively, you could load the `comment` package and surround the code chunk in question with `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` statements, on lines by themselves.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,cprotect,comment}
\begin{document}

\begin{comment}
\cprotect\section{my title with some math $\sin x$}
    this is a test
\end{comment}

test
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately `\cprotect` is defined to be `\outer` a totally useless TeX primitive feature that is not really used in LaTeX at all. The only effect of declaring a command to be `\outer` is to make it throw an error in certain constructs deemed not to be "top level" and a region being skipped by an `\if` test is one of the disallowed contexts.

`\outer` is an error-detecting mechanism that has generated orders of magnitude more errors than it ever caught.

As you are using luatex you can disable the whole mechanism with `\suppressoutererror`.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cprotect}

\suppressoutererror = 1

\begin{document}


\iffalse
\cprotect\section{my title with some math $\sin x$}
    this is a test
\fi

test
\end{document}
```

Alternatively the package provides `\icprotect` which is a non-outer version of the command.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cprotect}

%\suppressoutererror = 1

\begin{document}


\iffalse
\icprotect\section{my title with some math $\sin x$}
    this is a test
\fi

test
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks David. good information. I also switched to using comment package. Much better it seems than using `\iffalse` to comment code.